How to open/edit a node group in a new window via python?
Let's say, I have a node group.

I want to open a new window where I can edit this node group.

Note: it should work with any node group and nested node group.

Edit Node Group in new window (Shading node groups only)
import bpy

def main(node_tree):
    windows = bpy.context.window_manager.windows
    ws = set(windows)

    bpy.ops.wm.window_new("INVOKE_DEFAULT")

    new_window,  = set(windows) - ws


    area = new_window.screen.areas[0]
    area.type = "NODE_EDITOR"
    area.ui_type = "ShaderNodeTree"
    space_data = area.spaces[0]

    space_data.show_region_header = False
    space_data.pin = True
    space_data.show_region_ui = False

    space_data.node_tree = node_tree

class NodeEditGroupNewWin(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "node.edit_group_new_win"
    bl_label = "Edit Node Group in New Window"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        space = context.space_data
        if space.type == 'NODE_EDITOR': return True
    
        ob = context.object
        if hasattr(ob, 'type') and ob.type == 'MESH' and ob.active_material:
            material = ob.active_material
            if material.use_nodes and material.node_tree:
                return True
        return False

    def execute(self, context):
        if hasattr(context, 'active_node'):
            node = context.active_node
        else:
            node = context.object.active_material

        if node and hasattr(node, 'node_tree'): pass
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "Node Group not found")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if node.node_tree.type != 'SHADER':
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "Only support Shading node group")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        main(node.node_tree)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NodeEditGroupNewWin)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NodeEditGroupNewWin)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    
    # Test call, select a node group in shader editor first
    try:
        area = next(a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas  if a.type == "NODE_EDITOR")
        with bpy.context.temp_override(area=area):
            bpy.ops.node.edit_group_new_win()
    except:
        print('NODE_EDITOR not found, test in Viewport')
        area = next(a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas  if a.type == "VIEW_3D")
        with bpy.context.temp_override(area=area):
            bpy.ops.node.edit_group_new_win()


The new one can be run in 3Dviewport.
